# Android, how to get the version number of sqlite DB file that backuped in SD card?

Tags: android, sqlite, version, restore, downgrade

Here is my problem:

Preconditions:

1, APP backup the db file to SD card, assuming the DB version is 2.

2, Uninstall APP on phone.

Now, installing an old version APP with old version DB (like, 1).

APP has to restore the backup DB file from SD card for initializing UI.

Problem is that I can NOT get the version number of the backup DB file!

Further more, I can NOT decide should it "upgrade" or "downgrade"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(back_up_db_path, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE).[getVersion()](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/blob/master/src/net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteDatabase.java#L985) method. May be help you.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can understand from the question, I think you just want to know the version of your db file stored in the sdcard. If that's the case then you could try opening the db file from tools like sqliteman and run `PRAGMA user_version;`. It would return the version number of the db.